# Laravel & Vue.js. I Can't Fix My Code

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on an application to manage some Cvs.

All my resource functions work perfectly (creating and editing new Cvs etc.)

But in my Vue.js part, it's about showing details for every Cv in a show view using Axios to get data from the database or post using a form.

My console shows a reactivity problem about my variables: `infos` and `info`.

Here is my **show.blade.php** code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class ="container" id="app">
<div class="container" id="app">
 <div class ="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="panel-panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-18"> <h3 class="panel-title"> Experience </h3></div>
                 <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                      <button class="btn btn-success" > Ajouter</button>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>     

    <div class="panel-body" >
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="info in infos">
              <div class="pull-right">
                   <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>
               </div>
                   <h3>@{{ info.titre }}</h3>
                   <p>@{{ info.body }}</p>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div >
        <form class="flex flex-col" @submit.prevent="addExperience">
             <textarea class="border rounded p-2 mp-3" v-model="info.titre"></textarea>
             <textarea class="border rounded p-2 mp-3" v-model="info.body"></textarea>
             <button type="submit" class="border rounded py-2">Commenter</button>
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('javascripts')

<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.js')}}"> </script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
        window.Laravel={!! json_encode([
           'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
           'idExperience' => $id,
           'url' =>url('/')]) !!} ;
</script>
<script>
        var app= new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
        message: '',
        infos: [],
        info:{
            id:0,
            cv_id:window.Laravel.idExperience,
            titre:'',
            body:'',
        }},
        methods:{
            getExperiences: function() {
                axios.get(window.Laravel.url+'/getexperiences/'+window.Laravel.idExperience)
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(reponse.data);
                    this.info=reponse.data;})
                .catch(error =>{
                    console.log('errors: ', error);})},
            addExperience:function(){
                axios.post(window.Laravel.url+'/addexperience', this.info)
                .then(repsonse => {
                if(response.data.etat){

                this.infos.unshift(this.info);
                this.info={
            id:0,
            cv_id:window.Laravel.idExperience,
            titre:'',
            body:'',
                };}})
                 .catch(error =>{
                    console.log('errors: ', error)})},
         created:function(){
         this.getExperiences();})};   
</script>    
@endsection
```

And my two functions get Experiences and addExperience in CvController:

```
    public function getExperiences($id){
$cv= Cv::find($id);
return $cv->infos;   
}

public function addExperience(Request $request){
$info = new Info;
$info->titre=$request->titre;
$info->body=$request->body;
$info->cv_id=$request->cv_id;
$info->save();

return response()->json(['etat'=> true, 'id'=> $info->id]);

}
```

And these are my routes:

```
Route::resource('cvs','CvController'); 
Route::get('/getexperiences/{id}', 'CvController@getExperiences');
Route::post('/addexperience', 'CvController@addExperience');
```

My console:

[image: My console]

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors that need to be fixed first.

- There's an extra ")" at the end of your `created` method
- The `methods` property is missing a closing "}"
- There's a missing ")" at the very end to match the opening `new Vue(` parenthesis.

It's helpful to indent your code to make these things easier to spot.

Then, you'll need to update your data to be a function that returns an object. See [Vue Docs - Data Must Be a Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

You also have some typos for the "response" variable.

Lastly, in your HTML you have two divs that have `id="app"`.

Your JS should look something like:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: '',
        infos: [],
        info: {
            id: 0,
            cv_id: window.Laravel.idExperience,
            titre: '',
            body: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getExperiences: function () {
            axios.get(window.Laravel.url + '/getexperiences/' + window.Laravel.idExperience)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(reponse.data);
                    this.info = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('errors: ', error);
                })
        },
        addExperience: function () {
            axios.post(window.Laravel.url + '/addexperience', this.info)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.etat) {

                        this.infos.unshift(this.info);
                        this.info = {
                            id: 0,
                            cv_id: window.Laravel.idExperience,
                            titre: '',
                            body: '',
                        };
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('errors: ', error)
                })
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getExperiences();
        }
    }
});
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you :)
But still doenst work.  The same error message.. I didnt change your reply code. it is correct ?